Getting [Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMNodeInserted' mutation event warning while using in react
While using the latest react-quill ^2.0.0, getting the warning in browser on every load in line (quill.js:4237):
[Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMNodeInserted' mutation event. This event type is deprecated, and will be removed from this browser very soon. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a large risk of future site breakage. Consider using MutationObserver instead. See https://chromestatus.com/feature/5083947249172480 for more information.

Please guide if someone resolve it or rectified.
